# Insert Row and Total amount on basis of Column B and sort group

Tags: vba, excel

As per given data below I want to total on the basis of Assignment which is column B by inserting a row below it and total its amount in 2 columns Column C and E.Also after that i want to sort that group on basis of date which is column G.

I tried many codes from google and other places but not worked . Please help what code we can use.

```
   A           B          C          D      E        F     G           H    
1100000014  Expat     -63,126.82    BGN -32,276.23  EUR 07/22/2015  07/17/2015
100009284   Expat     -31,225.08    BGN -31,225.08  BGN 06/19/2015  06/19/2015
100009284   others     11,558.90    BGN  11,558.90  BGN 06/19/2015  06/19/2015
100009339   GLSC          621.96    BGN     318.00  EUR 06/25/2015  06/08/2015
100012975   markeing    10,147.39   BGN  10,147.39  BGN 10/01/2015  09/30/2015
```

Output should look like this:

```
     A         B          C          D      E        F     G           H    

    100009284   Expat     -31,225.08    BGN -31,225.08  BGN 06/19/2015  06/19/2015
1100000014    Expat    -63,126.82   BGN -32,276.23  EUR 07/22/2015  07/17/2015
    Expat Total            xxxxxxx           xxxxxx     
    100009284   others     11,558.90    BGN  11,558.90  BGN 06/19/2015  06/19/2015
    Others Total           xxxxx              xxxxxx         
    100009339   GLSC          621.96    BGN     318.00  EUR 06/25/2015  06/08/2015
    GLSC Total                xxxxx              xxxxxx
    100012975   markeing    10,147.39   BGN  10,147.39  BGN 10/01/2015  09/30/2015
    Marketing Total          xxxxx            xxxxxxx
```

Comment: more info required..do you mean you want to total Column C and column "E"??how many of these groups are in the page? do you want to sort the groups or all records?

Comment: @neuralgroove  yes on basis of Column B

Comment: maybe it would help for you to update your question with a sample of how you want the output to look

Comment: your results are not sorted by column G, did you forget that part?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will create the output you have provided in your question, Column G is sorted in ascending order, unlike your sample output, based on your question, if that isn't correct then you can adjust the VBA.

```
    Option Explicit
Sub SortAndTotal()
Dim LastRow As Long
Dim ws As Worksheet
Dim r As Long
Dim ColCTotal As Double
Dim ColETotal As Double

    Set ws = ActiveSheet
    LastRow = ws.Cells(100000, 1).End(xlUp).Row

    With ws.Sort.SortFields
        .Clear
        .Add Key:=Range("B1:B" & LastRow)
        .Add Key:=Range("G1:G" & LastRow)
    End With
    With ws.Sort
        .SetRange Range("A1:H" & LastRow)
        .Header = xlNo
        .Apply
    End With

    r = 1
    ColCTotal = 0
    ColETotal = 0
    While ws.Cells(r, 1) <> ""
        ColCTotal = ColCTotal + ws.Cells(r, 3)
        ColETotal = ColETotal + ws.Cells(r, 5)
        If ws.Cells(r, 2) <> ws.Cells(r + 1, 2) Then
            ws.Cells(r + 1, 1).EntireRow.Insert shift:=xlDown
            ws.Cells(r + 1, 1) = ws.Cells(r, 2) & " Total"
            ws.Cells(r + 1, 3) = ColCTotal
            ws.Cells(r + 1, 5) = ColETotal
            ColCTotal = 0
            ColETotal = 0
            r = r + 2
        Else
            r = r + 1
        End If
    Wend
End Sub
```

Comment: I updated the answer, I think you have Option Explicit on, which means all your variables have to be declared.

Comment: that option explicit is open because of my code review last time. In code review in Stackoverflow people asked me to make it activated and re modify code which i am doing with help of you guys... Thank you so much. I will check and comment on code again today.l

Comment: its still creating debug error on ColCTotal = ColCTotal + ws.Cells(r, 3)

Comment: I asked my friend he modified for me and made it work . I might be working wrong with code might be.